# Unexpected Behavior from Integrate with PrincipalValue -> True

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, symbolic, warning-messages

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and persisting through 12.1 or later.   Reported to Wolfram, Inc. as CASE:4544446.**

The following code, taken from my [answer to 97024](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97121/1063),

```
Integrate[1/((1 - 4 ωp^2 - 4 I ωp γ) (1 - ωp^2 - 2 I ωp γ)^2 (ωp - ω)), 
    {ωp, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> γ > 0 && ω > 0, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

runs for 41 minutes on *Mathematica*

```
$Version
(* 10.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 7, 2015) *)
```

before returning unevaluated, in the process twice giving the two error messages,

```
Limit::cas: Warning: contradictory assumption(s) False&&ωp>4096 encountered. >>
Integrate::idiv: Integral of ... does not converge on does not converge on {-∞,∞}. >>
```

neither of which is valid.  Omitting the term, `(1 - ωp^2 - 2 I ωp γ)^2` or setting `ω -> 0` produces the same outcome, only faster.  In fact, the only variant I have been able to make work is to set `γ` to a numerical value, here `3`.

```
Integrate[1/((1 - 4 ωp^2 - 4 I ωp 3) (1 - ωp^2 - 2 I ωp 3)^2 (ωp - ω)), 
    {ωp, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> ω > 0, PrincipalValue -> True]
(* -((I π)/((-1 + 4 ω (3 I + ω)) (-1 + ω (6 I + ω))^2)) *)
```

Is there some work-around for this problem, not involving evaluation of residues?

**Issues persist in 10.3**

With

```
$Version
(* 10.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 9, 2015) *)
```

a simpler version of the code above,

```
Integrate[1/((1 - 4 ωp^2 - 4 I ωp γ) (ωp - ω)), {ωp, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
    Assumptions -> γ > 0 && ω > 0, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

produces the same spurious error messages as before, although it takes twice as long to do so (about eight minutes).  Incidentally, a still faster way to reproduce this problem is

```
Integrate[1/(-(ωp - 1/2 (-I γ - Sqrt[1 - γ^2])) (ωp - ω)), {ωp, -∞, ∞}, 
    Assumptions -> γ > 0 && ω ∈ Reals, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

which takes only seconds.  Note that I also replaced `ω > 0` by `ω ∈ Reals` to see whether it mattered.  It does not.

**Issues persist for 12.1**

Mathematica 12.1 now can solve the first integral given under "Issues persist in 10.3" (in just over two minutes), but the answer is wrong.

```
(* ConditionalExpression[(Pi*(I*γ - Sqrt[1 - γ^2] + 2*ω))/(Sqrt[1 - γ^2]*
   (I + 4*(γ - I*ω)*ω)), γ < 1] *)
```

as can be seen from summing the residues,

```
Residue[1/((1 - 4 ωp^2 - 4 I ωp γ) (ωp - ω)), {ωp, #}] & /@ 
    (ωp /. Solve[((1 - 4 ωp^2 - 4 I ωp γ) (ωp - ω)) == 0, ωp])
(* {-(1/(2 Sqrt[1 - γ^2] (I γ + Sqrt[1 - γ^2] + 2 ω))),
    -(1/(2 Sqrt[1 - γ^2] (-I γ + Sqrt[1 - γ^2] - 2 ω))), 
    I/(I + 4 γ ω - 4 I ω^2)} *)

Simplify[2 π I (Total[%] - Last[%]/2)]
(* π/(I + 4 γ ω - 4 I ω^2) *)
```

The other integrals given in this question either return unevaluated with error messages or run indefinitely.

Comment: I believe the `ωp>4096` comes from an internal `Limit` making an assumption, if it's any help `Trace`-ing down the problem...I'll probably delete this, as it probably won't prove to be much help.  But it's all the time I got right now. :)

Comment: @MichaelE2  I tried `Trace` but did not learn much.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: If I followed the computation correctly, `Integrate` mistakenly concludes that all the roots of the denominator lie on the real line: http://i.stack.imgur.com/peMwW.png -- no time to investigate further right now

Comment: @MichaelE2  Thanks for continuing to investigate this question.  How did you obtain the `PV limits`?  I did not obtain them with `Trace`.  You may be correct that `Integrate` thinks they are on the real axis, but that would be really strange, because the expressions contain `I`.  By the way, I installed 10.3 this morning and shall rerun this calculation with it.  Quite slow, though.

Comment: [``Internal`Integrate`debugSwitch``](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89185/integrate-yielding-a-conditionalexpression-but-i-dont-think-the-condition-is-ne/89190#89190).  Almost 10MB of output, so beware. (My institution is slow about making available new versions, so no 10.3 for me yet.)

Comment: Hello, friends, am I wrong to expect some response to my answer?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze  I usually wait a bit to allow multiple readers to respond before accepting an answer, but I probably have waited long enough.  Although the use of `Apply` and `Apart` certainly increase the speed greatly, the key part of your solution (from my perspective) is performing the integral over a finite range and then taking the limit as the domain goes to infinity, because this avoids the spurious error messages.  Would you agree that the error messages constitute a bug?

Comment: @ bbgodfrey I didn't have in mind the acceptance of my solution, but a discussion about it, as there are several things to mention: more important than the acceleration of the calculation are 1) taking the symmetric limit of a integral ober a finite range, 2) the intermediate use of symbolic parameters 3) the necessity of calculating the roots explicitly 4) the necessity of converting the sum to  list in the integrand in order to get "digestable" pieces. I shall put this into my answers. Please let me think about the question in your comment. Maybe the case can be stated even simpler.

Comment: I look forward to your additional material.  With respect to accepting your solution, I have never failed to accept the best real solution but I do wait a bit.  Your comment reminded me that it was time to accept your solution, and I took no offense at the reminder, whether intended or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting exercise. It can be done with some preparatory steps in a few seconds of computing time.

The OP asks for the integral

```
q := Integrate[h, {ωp, -∞, ∞}, 
  Assumptions -> {γ > 0, ω > 0}, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

where the integrand is

```
h = 1/((1 - 4 ωp^2 - 
     4 I ωp γ) (1 - ωp^2 - 
      2 I ωp γ)^2 (ωp - ω));
```

*Compact answer*

Letting

```
g = 1/((x - a) (x - b) (x - c) (x - d)^2 (x - f)^2);
rep = Thread[{b, c, d, d, f, f, a} -> (ωp /. Solve[0 == 1/h, ωp])];
```

we have

```
Simplify[h == (-1/4) g /. rep /. x -> ωp]

(*
Out[145]= True
*)
```

and the integral becomes

```
q = Timing[(-1/4) Simplify[
    Plus @@ Limit[
       Integrate[List @@ Apart[g], {x, -z, z}, PrincipalValue -> True, 
        Assumptions -> {z > 0, a ∈ Reals, Im[b] != 0, Im[c] != 0, 
          Im[d] != 0, Im[f] != 0}], z -> ∞] /. rep]]
{14.2116911`, -((
  2 π)/((I + 4 γ ω - 4 I ω^2) (2 γ ω - 
     I (-1 + ω^2))^2))}
```

and it is done in less that 15 seconds (Version 10.1. on a normal Windows Laptop).

*Detailed derivation*

We show here that the integral can in fact be calculated refraining from the use of evaluating residues.
The main idea is to understand the integral as a limit z->∞ of the finite integral between -z and z.
Also, an explicit partial fraction decomposition using Apart[] helps reduce the computing time.

Determining explcitly the roots of the denominator

```
sol = Solve[0 == 1/h, ωp]

(*
Out[70]= {{ωp -> 1/2 (-I γ - Sqrt[1 - γ^2])}, {ωp -> 
   1/2 (-I γ + Sqrt[1 - γ^2])}, {ωp -> -I γ - 
    I Sqrt[-1 + γ^2]}, {ωp -> -I γ - 
    I Sqrt[-1 + γ^2]}, {ωp -> -I γ + 
    I Sqrt[-1 + γ^2]}, {ωp -> -I γ + 
    I Sqrt[-1 + γ^2]}, {ωp -> ω}}
*)
```

Letting

```
p = ωp /. sol

(*
Out[88]= {1/2 (-I γ - Sqrt[1 - γ^2]), 
 1/2 (-I γ + Sqrt[1 - γ^2]), -I γ - 
  I Sqrt[-1 + γ^2], -I γ - 
  I Sqrt[-1 + γ^2], -I γ + 
  I Sqrt[-1 + γ^2], -I γ + I Sqrt[-1 + γ^2], ω}
*)
```

We find

```
Simplify[4 Times @@ (ωp - p) == -1/h]

(*
Out[89]= True
*)
```

Assuming general parameters defined in this replacement

```
rep = Thread[{b, c, d, d, f, f, a} -> p]

(*
Out[90]= {b -> 1/2 (-I γ - Sqrt[1 - γ^2]), 
 c -> 1/2 (-I γ + Sqrt[1 - γ^2]), 
 d -> -I γ - I Sqrt[-1 + γ^2], 
 d -> -I γ - I Sqrt[-1 + γ^2], 
 f -> -I γ + I Sqrt[-1 + γ^2], 
 f -> -I γ + I Sqrt[-1 + γ^2], a -> ω}
*)
```

We shall consider the integral of the more general expression for the integrand (for ease of reading we let `ωp -> x`)

```
g = 1/((x - a) (x - b) (x - c) (x - d)^2 (x - f)^2);

g /. rep /. x -> ωp // Simplify

(*
Out[97]= -(4/((ω - ωp) (-1 + 
    2 I γ ωp + ωp^2)^2 (-1 + 4 I γ ωp + 
    4 ωp^2)))
*)
```

The integral over g is then -4 times the integral in question, i.e. q = -g/4.

Before taking the integral It helps decomposing g into partial fractions, and splitting it into a list

```
ga = List @@ Apart[g]

(*
Out[107]= {1/((a - b) (a - c) (a - d)^2 (a - f)^2 (-a + x)), -(
  1/((a - b) (b - c) (b - d)^2 (b - f)^2 (-b + x))), -(
  1/((a - c) (-b + c) (c - d)^2 (c - f)^2 (-c + x))), -(
  1/((a - d) (-b + d) (-c + d) (d - f)^2 (-d + x)^2)), (
 2 a b c - 3 a b d - 3 a c d - 3 b c d + 4 a d^2 + 4 b d^2 + 4 c d^2 - 5 d^3 +
   a b f + a c f + b c f - 2 a d f - 2 b d f - 2 c d f + 
  3 d^2 f)/((a - d)^2 (-b + d)^2 (-c + d)^2 (d - f)^3 (-d + x)), -(
  1/((b - f) (-a + f) (-c + f) (-d + f)^2 (-f + x)^2)), (
 2 a b c + a b d + a c d + b c d - 3 a b f - 3 a c f - 3 b c f - 2 a d f - 
  2 b d f - 2 c d f + 4 a f^2 + 4 b f^2 + 4 c f^2 + 3 d f^2 - 
  5 f^3)/((a - f)^2 (-b + f)^2 (-c + f)^2 (-d + f)^3 (-f + x))}
*)
```

Now the integral over the list ga is quickly calculated

```
gai = Timing[
  Integrate[ga, {x, -z, z}, PrincipalValue -> True, 
   Assumptions -> {z > 0, a ∈ Reals, Im[b] != 0, Im[c] != 0, 
     Im[d] != 0, Im[f] != 0}]]

(*
Out[110]= {15.8029, {(-Log[-a - z] + 
   Log[-a + z])/((a - b) (a - c) (a - d)^2 (a - f)^2), (-Log[b - z] + 
   Log[b + z])/((a - b) (b - c) (b - d)^2 (b - f)^2), (-Log[c - z] + 
   Log[c + z])/((a - c) (-b + c) (c - d)^2 (c - f)^2), -((
   2 z)/((a - d) (-b + d) (-c + d) (d - f)^2 (d^2 - 
      z^2))), ((d (-3 b c + 4 (b + c) d - 5 d^2) + (b c - 2 (b + c) d + 
        3 d^2) f + 
     a (2 b c - 3 b d - 3 c d + 4 d^2 + (b + c - 2 d) f)) (Log[d - z] - 
     Log[d + z]))/((a - d)^2 (b - d)^2 (c - d)^2 (d - f)^3), -((
   2 z)/((b - f) (d - f)^2 (-a + f) (-c + f) (f^2 - z^2))), ((2 a b c + 
     a b d + a c d + 
     b c d - (3 b c + 3 a (b + c) + 2 (a + b + c) d) f + (4 (a + b + c) + 
        3 d) f^2 - 5 f^3) (Log[f - z] - Log[f + z]))/((a - f)^2 (b - f)^2 (c -
      f)^2 (-d + f)^3)}}
*)
```

Now taking the limit z->∞

```
gail = Timing[Limit[gi[[2]], z -> ∞]]

(*
Out[111]= {0.265202, {-((I π)/((a - b) (a - c) (a - d)^2 (a - f)^2)), -((
   I π)/((a - b) (b - c) (b - d)^2 (b - f)^2)), -((
   I π)/((a - c) (-b + c) (c - d)^2 (c - f)^2)), 0, (
  I (d (-3 b c + 4 (b + c) d - 5 d^2) + (b c - 2 (b + c) d + 3 d^2) f + 
     a (2 b c - 3 b d - 3 c d + 4 d^2 + (b + c - 2 d) f)) π)/((a - 
     d)^2 (b - d)^2 (c - d)^2 (d - f)^3), 0, (
  I (2 a b c + a b d + a c d + 
     b c d - (3 b c + 3 a (b + c) + 2 (a + b + c) d) f + (4 (a + b + c) + 
        3 d) f^2 - 5 f^3) π)/((a - f)^2 (b - f)^2 (c - f)^2 (-d + f)^3)}}
*)
```

and summing up the terms

```
gs = Plus @@ gail[[2]]

(*
Out[117]= -((I π)/((a - b) (a - c) (a - d)^2 (a - f)^2)) - (
 I π)/((a - b) (b - c) (b - d)^2 (b - f)^2) - (
 I π)/((a - c) (-b + c) (c - d)^2 (c - f)^2) + (
 I (2 a b c + a b d + a c d + 
    b c d - (3 b c + 3 a (b + c) + 2 (a + b + c) d) f + (4 (a + b + c) + 
       3 d) f^2 - 5 f^3) π)/((a - f)^2 (b - f)^2 (c - f)^2 (-d + f)^3) + (
 I (d (-3 b c + 4 (b + c) d - 5 d^2) + (b c - 2 (b + c) d + 3 d^2) f + 
    a (2 b c - 3 b d - 3 c d + 4 d^2 + (b + c - 2 d) f)) π)/((a - 
    d)^2 (b - d)^2 (c - d)^2 (d - f)^3)
*)
```

Replacing the parameters

```
gsrep = gs /. rep // Simplify

(*
Out[120]= (8 π)/((I + 4 γ ω - 4 I ω^2) (2 γ ω - 
   I (-1 + ω^2))^2)
*)
```

Hence the original integral is simply

```
q = -1/4 gsrep
```

$$q = -\frac{2 \pi }{\left(4 \gamma  \omega -4 i \omega ^2+i\right) \left(2 \gamma  \omega -i \left(\omega ^2-1\right)\right)^2}$$

Done.